# Non-Structured software for drawing, text & mind mapping

Tags: software-rec, drawing, mind-mapping

What could be a non structured software for drawing, text, mind-mapping something to quickly lay down your ideas, Similar to [VUE](http://vue.tufts.edu/) but much more liberal with respect to the following points:

- Preferably open source.
- Freely sketching at any part of the document.
- Placing Images(any size) at any part of the document.
- Placing text at any part of the document.
- Linking up the above blocks using various elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a popular open source Mind Mapping package.

Comment: freemind is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

[iMindMap](http://www.imindmap.com/v4release/) seems to fit your requirements. It works also on Windows, MacOS X and Linux.

Excerpt from the FAQ:

> **What makes iMindMap different from other Mind Mapping software?**
>
> Where many other Mind Mapping programs are rigid and linear, iMindMap uses 
>   the principles laid out by Tony Buzan, the inventor of Mind Maps. 
>   These “rules” state that by creating organic‐looking, colourful, structured and image‐filled Mind Maps, the brain remembers and processes the 
>   information contained within the Mind Map much more effectively.
>   Thus increasing productivity, creativity, imagination and inspiration for the creator.  
>   This results in saved time and a better quality outcome for the task carried out.

Comment: The softwares listed are more based on a central theme and expand from that point, I am looking for a more free handed approach.

Comment: Then you need simply a vector graphic program, Inkscape for instance.